# Why do I need boundedness for a a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$ to have a maximum?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, examples-counterexamples, real-numbers, maxima-minima

Doesn't closedness suffice? If not, do you have a counterexample?

Comment: In fact, *any* (EDIT: upper) unbounded closed set is a counterexample. You should always test your guess on a nontrivial example (in this case, think of a single (EDIT: upper) unbounded closed set and see if it has a maximum).

Comment: @NoahSchweber: $(-\infty,0]$ is an unbounded closed set that is not a counterexample.

Comment: @NoahSchweber By "unbounded", you mean "not upper bounded" I assume. But basically... your comment is a rephrasing of the question.

Comment: @ClementC. I didn't mean it to be an answer (hence why it's just a comment), but advice to the OP: if they first try to think of an example of an upper-unbounded (thank you!) closed set, that will probably be an easier task, as will subsequently checking if it has a maximum or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, being closed isn't enough. $\mathbb N$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb R$ without a maximum.

Answer (score 5):

No, take the whole real line for example. It is closed, but does it have a maximum?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there are counterexamples: $\mathbb{R}$ is closed.